# Getting the sub length of a Object[][] array

Tags: java, arrays

The title is self-explanantory, but I ask it as a question: Is there a way to get a sub-length of a two-dimensional array? E.g

```
Vec2 vectors[][] = {{new Vec2(x1,y1),new Vec2(x2,y2)},{new Vec2(x3,y3),new Vec2(x4,y4),new Vec2(x5,y5)}};
```

Comment: Sub-length? You mean like `vectors[n].length`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java multi dimenstional arrays are [jagged arrays](http://way2java.com/arrays/jagged-arrays-varying-column-size-arrays/).
So there is no direct way to get length of array of array(sub array).Instead you can get the sub array and get `length` on it.

Comment: Would it be like(after declaring): `vector[i].length();`?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed when I clicked on the link. Before my comment I was completely oblivious to the link.